# What level of radiation protection do electronics on the ISS or in LEO need?

Tags: iss, low-earth-orbit, radiation, electronics

The harsh radiation environment in space requires that electronics on spacecraft be "radiation hardened."  However, the radiation environment in LEO is not as intense as say a spacecraft traveling through the Van Allen belts.  I'm wondering what level of radiation hardening is needed for spacecraft in LEO or payloads going to the ISS.  A link to a NASA or other agency requirements document would be appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/how-often-are-iss-computers-mdms-replaced